# What happens when I loop a dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I know `Python` will simply return the key list when I put a `dict` in `for...in...` syntax.

But what what happens to the dict?

When we use `help(dict)`, we can not see `__next()__` method in the method list. So if I want to make a derived class based on `dict`:

```
class MyDict(dict)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and **return the value list with `for...in...`**

```
d = Mydict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
for value in d:
```

what should I do?

Comment: Why should `dict` have `__next__`? It has `__iter__`, and the object which that function returns supports `next`. Your class `MyClass` inherits `__iter__` from its base class `dict`, so it has the same behaviour as `dict`.

Comment: Just a note: this may confuse you or others later down the road: everyone would expect to iterate over the keys, and suddenly we get values here (even if your variable is named `value`). Just use `for value in d.values()` instead; that's clear without a doubt what's going on.

Comment: I believe the `yield` keyword and [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) are what you're looking for.

Comment: Just have `__iter__` return the iterator for a list of the values, e.g. return iter( d.values() )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naively, if all you want is for iteration over an instance of `MyClass` to yield the values instead of the keys, then in `MyClass` define:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self.itervalues()
```

In Python 3:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.values())
```

But beware! By doing this your class no longer implements the contract of `collections.MutableMapping`, even though `issubclass(MyClass, collections.MutableMapping)` is True. You might be better off *not* subclassing `dict`, if this is the behaviour you want, but instead have an attribute of type `dict` to hold the data, and implement only the functions and operators you need.